# How to get URL for current portalpage in Websphere Portal 8.0

Tags: websphere-portal

I need to extract the current portalpage URL in Websphere Portal 8 on a content page. To do this I found a component called "UrlCmpnt".

But when I try to use it I cannot get it to print the full page URL. For example:

I'm on the page: *mysite.com/testPage1*

This page has the following component: *[URLCmpnt context="current" type="content" mode="standalone"]*

And that generates the following string: */wps/wcm/connect/tree_structure/to_page/testPage1*

Can I use this component to generate *mysite.com/testPage1* or is there another way in Websphere Portal 8 to do this? I wan't to avoid doing this in javascript if it's possible.

Link to documentation for "UrlCmpnt": http://library.nu.edu.kz/wps/iehs/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.admin.help/wcm/wcm_dev_item-details_url.html

Comment: It seems you using plain WCM to display your content, it displaying through WCM servlet (/wps/wcm/connect/) and contains you content full path. If you want get urls like this (mysite.com/testPage1) you should use portal pages and JSR 286 portlet.

Comment: But I am using a portal page with JSR 286 to display the content.

Comment: @boston Have you got any solution to this?